# Split one long column into multiple smaller columns in excel

Tags: excel

What is the best way to copy paste in groups of 15 items if you have a list of over 7000 items? If anyone has a better method than the following, please let me know , i am using excel 2003

I have a long list of 7000 items from column A1 to A7000. I would like to split this up into different columns (B,C,D...etc) in groups of 15. In other words, how do I make column:

```
B1:B15 include items A1:A15. 

C1:C15 include items A16:A30. 

D1:D15 include items A31:A45 etc...
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Using VBA? If yes, then can you show what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.  Someone may come by with more optimized code.

Gordon

```
Sub split_data()
Dim lastRow As Long, copynumRow As Long
Dim cRow As Long, cCol As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

copynumRow = 15
cCol = 2
cRow = 1 + copynumRow

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Do While cRow <= lastRow
        .Range("A" & cRow).Resize(copynumRow, 1).Cut _
            Destination:=.Cells(1, cCol).Resize(copynumRow, 1)

        cRow = cRow + copynumRow
        cCol = cCol + 1
    Loop
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create an Excel Macro and it'll automatically do the need full, even it there are lac's of records.

Comment: can you please advise how to that a I am begginer thanks in advance